# ASP.Net LINQ data source error is ListView

Tags: asp.net, linq, listview, evaluation

I have a successful query that is returning 8 items from REST_NAME columen of the RESTAURANT db.  I have a successful databind but when I try to access the item in the LivtView I receive an error:  'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'REST_NAME'.

**LINQ query from Data Access Layer:**

```
public IEnumerable<string> getRestaurants(int cuisineID)
{
    var restaurantList = from RESTAURANT in db.RESTAURANTs
                         where RESTAURANT.CUISINE_ID == cuisineID
                         orderby RESTAURANT.REST_NAME ascending
                         select RESTAURANT.REST_NAME;
    return restaurantList;
}
```

**Function in Business Logic Layer:**

```
public class BLgetRestaurants
{
    public IEnumerable<string> getRestaurants(int cuisineID)
    {
        DLgetRestaurants obj = new DLgetRestaurants();
        var restaurantList = obj.getRestaurants(cuisineID);
        return restaurantList;
    }
}
```

**Front End call of Business Layer function:**

```
BLgetRestaurants obj = new BLgetRestaurants();
var restaurantListing = obj.getRestaurants(cuisineID);
ListRestaurants.DataSource = restaurantListing;
ListRestaurants.DataBind();
```

*Finally, the ListView call to get the REST_NAME data:**

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <div id="RestName"><%#Eval("REST_NAME") %></div><br />
     <div id="ListItems">
          <div id="RestCuisine">Cuisine: </div>
          <div id="RestCity">Location: </div>
          <div id="RestAvgRating">Average Rating: </div>
          <div id="RestPrice">Price: </div> 
     </div>  
</ItemTemplate>
```

Thanks for your help!
~susan~

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
 <div id="RestName"><%# Container.DataItem %></div><br />
```

You can use `<%#Eval("REST_NAME") %>` if you are dealing with `IEnumerable<Restaurant>` which has `REST_NAME` as one of it's fields. But since you are using `IEnumerable<string>` you cannot do that.

Comment: Thank you!!!  I'm trying to teach myself LINQ and have been struggling a bit.  Your help was greatly appreciated.